# A group closed under scalar multiplication is a vector space

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is an abelian group closed under scalar multiplication with elements in the field $F$. Is $G$ always a vector space over $F$?

I have been trying to find a counter-example, but failing. In such counter-example, at least one of the following needs not to hold for some $u,v \in G$, $a,b \in F$:

- $a(u+v)=au+av$
- $(a+b)u=au+bu$
- $a(bu)=(ab)u$

Thoughts/pointers appreciated.

Comment: Also should hold $1\cdot u=u$

Comment: So if we let $r\cdot u=0$, this not a vector space.

Comment: Ah neat, so just definiting multiplication by scalars in a trivial way does it. Thanks!